# TYPO3 - Cannot create a new extension with extension builder

Tags: php, typo3

I tried to create and save a new extension with Extension builder but an error appear :

```
Extension could not be saved: PHP Warning: symlink(): File exists in 
htdocs/public/typo3conf/ext/extension_builder/Classes/Controller/BuilderModuleController.php line 267
```

this line correspond at this part of code, I don't know if its useful :

```
265 if ($usesComposerPath && !is_link($publicExtensionDirectory)) {
266            symlink(
267                PathUtility::getRelativePath(dirname($publicExtensionDirectory), $extensionDirectory),
                $publicExtensionDirectory
            );
        }
```

I tried to update my extension builder,
I defined my file directory in the composer.json like that:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "public/typo3conf/ext"
        }
    ],
```

And I made a composer dump-autoload but the issue still persist

I don't know what's wrong, and I would gladly appreciate any idea.

thanks you in advance

Update : solved, it was an error in my path in "repositories :

```
    "repositories": {
        "local": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/home/server/vendor/htdocs/packages"
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your environment? OS, docker, etc?

Comment: For now your issue is done, but it’s always good to add version Infos to faster get your issue fixed. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a `packages` folder on the same directory level like the `public` folder.
Try this composer.json config:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "path",
    "url": "packages/*",
    "options": {
      "symlink": true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I solved it, and you right it's about the package folder

Answer (score 0):

Same error with TYPO3 V11 the solution was to change the owner of `ext` directory like:

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/site/public/typo3conf/ext
```